# Which iOS crash-reporting services are unreliable? (< 50% of bugs caught)

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I've tried Crashlytics, Crittercism, BugSense, and Flurry, and none of them seem to consistently report crashes. The first 3 just don't catch crashes that they claim to, and the last one explicitly doesn't catch low-level errors like de-referencing a NULL pointer. They miss a lot of them. Yesterday I created ~9 errors for Crashlytics, and it caught 3.

Have others had similar experiences? Is there a better crash reporting service? Or have I probably done something wrong to get bad data?

Comment: Could you show examples (code) of the crash types that are not reported? In-Process crash reporting iOS frameworks cannot catch crashes that are actually kills by the iOS system, see this page for more details: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/how-tos-faq/which-types-of-crashes-can-be-collected-on-ios-and-os-x

Comment: I tried out assertions, exceptions, all sorts of normal stuff with the phone unplugged from the computer

Comment: Excuse me, but if you want to know why some crashes are not being detected, you need to give examples. Otherwise you will not get any answers.